# MySQL - Combine Single Result Query & Multi Result Query into One

Tags: mysql, select

I have the 2 following Queries:

This table can have multiple lines per user (many photos) and I just want to return the number/count of photos:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos WHERE photo_description_profanity=1 AND photo_visible=1 AND photo_verified=1 AND userid='1000000002';
```

This table(s) is only one per user:

```
SELECT a.userid,a.profile_username,a.profile_gender,a.photo_name,a.photo_verified,b.profile_headline,
       YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(a.profile_birthdate) DAY)) AS age,d.city,c.english AS country
FROM login AS a
JOIN `profiles` AS b ON a.userid=b.userid 
JOIN geoCountry AS c ON a.profile_country=c.countryCode
JOIN geoWorld AS d ON a.profile_geo_location=d.pid
WHERE a.userid IN ('1000000002','1000000003','1000000004');
```

Is it possible to combine these 2 queries?

This is at my limit of ability so any advice would be great :) thx

Comment: Please show what you want the results to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.userid,
    a.profile_username,
    a.profile_gender,
    a.photo_name,
    a.photo_verified,
    b.profile_headline,
    YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), 
    INTERVAL TO_DAYS(a.profile_birthdate) DAY)) AS age,
    d.city,c.english AS country,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos WHERE photo_description_profanity=1 AND photo_visible=1 AND photo_verified=1 AND userid= a.userid) AS result_count
FROM login AS a
JOIN `profiles` AS b ON a.userid=b.userid 
JOIN geoCountry AS c ON a.profile_country=c.countryCode
JOIN geoWorld AS d ON a.profile_geo_location=d.pid
WHERE a.userid IN ('1000000002','1000000003','1000000004');
```

Comment: Hey thx so much... works great... didn't know I could add a select/query into a select like that... will remember... appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. this takes two steps:

- adapt the COUNT(*) into a filtering SUM()
- plug the source table into the query

.

```
SELECT a.userid,a.profile_username,a.profile_gender,a.photo_name,a.photo_verified,b.profile_headline,
       YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(a.profile_birthdate) DAY)) AS age,d.city,c.english AS country

//Here we insert the count column
,IFNULL(SUM(IF(photo_description_profanity=1 AND photo_visible=1 AND photo_verified=1,1,0)),0) AS photocount

FROM login AS a
JOIN `profiles` AS b ON a.userid=b.userid 
JOIN geoCountry AS c ON a.profile_country=c.countryCode
JOIN geoWorld AS d ON a.profile_geo_location=d.pid

//Here we insert the source table
LEFT JOIN photos ON photos.userid=a.userid

WHERE a.userid IN ('1000000002','1000000003','1000000004')

//Group by users
GROUP BY a.userid
```

Comment: This will return one row in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! GROUP BY section escaped my mouse in copy-paste mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this as an additional column, then cross join it into the results:

```
select const.cnt, . . . 
from (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM photos
      WHERE photo_description_profanity=1 AND photo_visible=1 AND
            photo_verified=1 AND userid='1000000002'
     ) const cross join
     login AS a
     JOIN `profiles` AS b ON a.userid=b.userid 
     JOIN geoCountry AS c ON a.profile_country=c.countryCode
     JOIN geoWorld AS d ON a.profile_geo_location=d.pid
//Here we insert the source table
     LEFT JOIN photos ON photos.userid=a.userid
WHERE a.userid IN ('1000000002','1000000003','1000000004');
```

The advantage of using a `cross join` instead of a nested select query is performance.  MySQL will execute the nested select for every row in the return set.  In the `from` clause, it will only be executed once.